# How to use mutable version of a library based on android sdk version at runtime?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

based on descriptions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video/v/4.2.0 , react-native-video not supported on SDK older than 26 .

for now I want to add a scenario that if android version to was older than 26 , then it(app) load compatible react-native-video version(3.2.1) otherwise be used last version of that library